# how do I present number of spaces in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am just learning Haskell. I am trying to present a number of spaces using a variable. For example, if I have a function:

```
function (a,x,b)
```

It should result in something like this

```
a ++ " "*(x) ++ b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a string with a given number of spaces with [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate), for example:

```
Prelude> replicate 0 ' '
""
Prelude> replicate 1 ' '
" "
Prelude> replicate 2 ' '
"  "
Prelude> replicate 3 ' '
"   "
```

I leave implementing the rest of the function as an exercise.